# Devise Override RegistrationController issue with resource.active_for_authentication?

Tags: ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to override this controller, in this moment the create method, I already made a little change on it

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    def create
      unless session[:invitation_token].blank?
        super
      else
        redirect_to new_user_session_path and return
      end
    end

end
```

after following the flow of sign up the resource is created in the database like the super class define it

```
  def create
    build_resource

    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
```

but in some way there is a problem with the method active_for_authetication?

Is throwing **false** and I can't figure out why I checked all the gem and it says that the method is overridden by other modules the normal definition is

```
def active_for_authentication?
  true
end
```

but I don't use any of the modules that override it so for some reason it seems like devise its not being able to succeed that validation but the user is stored in the database and I'm signed in after registration.

This is my configuration for register a user.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username
end
```

This is my Initializer for devise

```
Devise.setup do |config|

  config.mailer_sender = "please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com"

  require 'devise/orm/active_record'
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10
  config.password_length = 6..15
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
  config.sign_out_via = :delete


end
```